# How to return null instead of new object. ReadAsAsync<T>

Tags: c#, json, httpclient

By default ReadAsAsync will return new object T, even the response is empty json

> {}

For now my code looks like:

```
    public async Task<Resource> ResourceMetaInformation(ResourceMetaInfo model)
    {
        ThrowIfNullArgument(model);

        model.AsParametersForRequest();            
        string url = model.RequestUrl(this.api + "resources");
        using (var response = await client.GetAsync(url))
        {
            await ThrowIfIsNotOkResponse(response);
            // TODO: if response json is empty - return null. 

            return await response.Content.ReadAsAsync<Resource>();
        }
    }
```

For example rest api will return an empty json if is not founded a resource. Is a way to return null instead of new object.
And some additional question. Which will be the best approach for this situation - to return null or to throw an exception?

Comment: yo should get a `null` while awaiting on `ResourceMetaInformation`. Isn't it the case?

Comment: @Amit Kumar Ghosh yep